# How to use jquery ajax post similar to angular?

Tags: jquery, ajax, angular, angular8

I am having a legacy application which uses jquery. Currently it is not possible to use angular in this application.

I need to use a jquery ajax post method to consume a web service.

I am consuming the same web service with angular in another application, which works just fine. However when I try to use jquery it fails for some unknown reason

Below are the codes for Angular and Jquery. Could any one point out what am I missing.

**Angular**

```
let params = new HttpParams();
params.append('username',loginData.username);
params.append('password',loginData.password);    

const options = { headers: new HttpHeaders({'Content-Type': 'application/json'}) };
this._http.post('http://localhost/authenticate', 
loginData, options).subscribe(data => {  
    this.saveToken(data);
}, error => {
    alert('Invalid Credentials'); 
});
```

JQuery

```
jQuery.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost/authenticate",
    method: "POST",
    data: {username: "username", password: "password"},
    contentType: "application/json",
    processData: false,
    success: function(data, status){
        alert("Data: " + data + "\nStatus: " + status);
    }
});
```

I get http error 400 in case of jquery but in angular it is all fine.

The web service is a spring boot rest controller which accepts input data as @RequestBody

Answer (score 0):

Ok guys, I found the solution. I just had to stringify the input data like this

```
JSON.stringify({username: "username", password: "password"})
```